# preg_match() text extraction

Tags: regex, preg-match, text-extraction

I have this string inside a paragraph:

Today's quote is: 'Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. The important thing is not to stop questioning.'

I need to extract this sentence "Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. The important thing is not to stop questioning."

I am not familiar with regular expressions so I would like a little help here.
I tried:

```
preg_match("Today's quote is: '[a-zA-Z0-9]'",$response, $matches);
```

Off course as I imagined it's not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Also I need to include "_" and "-" with the alphanumeric expression.

Example:

`$string = "site : '6LcZwNcSAAAAAEcQkyCCSteouAQS9jO7wDrgzvbL', rtl : false, challenge : '03AHJ_Vuv_3y7kY-GQaCyzgrz9ZTv_cFQN_F0jEqOGNq0-3QANrsxJ18oPj4bbhRqPoISIZbqBBdeEXVfpnnVjlTsjoxQugI4j0zB1yRQU1m4wXzFGVRpuRyXJmnJU3d7Ix0nhyO_OBeFCR7v9gXtz_BNN04tSzXxVyvKCExO9I2vcqcIhWJQE8K8'";`

I need to match the string after the word "Challenge". Containing underscores and "-".

Comment: For extracting why not substr()? You sure you need a regEx?

Comment: You just need to get the part of the text inside the quotes?

Comment: @Barmar I need the part inside the quote

Comment: @MahmoudElSelimy do you have more examples of strings that you would need to extract?

Comment: @ExplosionPills the above string is present inside a paragraph that has similar formulas. So I need to make sure it has "Today's quote is:" before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
$string = "Today's quote is: 'Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. The important thing is not to stop questioning.'";
preg_match('/.*?:.*?\'(.*?)\'/', $string, $m);
echo $m[1]; // Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. The important thing is not to stop questioning.
```

EDIT2: After the OP has shown another example. Here's the solution for that edit:

```
$string = "site : '6LcZwNcSAAAAAEcQkyCCSteouAQS9jO7wDrgzvbL', rtl : false, challenge : '03AHJ_Vuv_3y7kY-GQaCyzgrz9ZTv_cFQN_F0jEqOGNq0-3QANrsxJ18oPj4bbhRqPoISIZbqBBdeEXVfpnnVjlTsjoxQugI4j0zB1yRQU1m4wXzFGVRpuRyXJmnJU3d7Ix0nhyO_OBeFCR7v9gXtz_BNN04tSzXxVyvKCExO9I2vcqcIhWJQE8K8'";
preg_match_all('/.*?:.*?\'(.*?)\'/', $string, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

Comment: Will this work even if it's inside a paragraph. I need to make sure that is has ""Today's quote is:" before it.

Comment: @MahmoudElSelimy "inside a paragraph" is really vague, I provided an answer to the current pattern `Today's quote is: '{match this}'`. So if you have other requirements, just tell us.

Comment: I added another example above. Hope that helps.

Comment: @MahmoudElSelimy See my edit, basically you can call the 2 values using `echo $m[1][0] .'<br>'. $m[1][1];` or just do a loop like this `foreach($m[1] as $extracted){ echo $extracted . '<br>';}`

Comment: Thanks alot for being up to date with me. I tried your example, tweaked it a bit and worked like a charm. what I did was:

    preg_match('/challenge.*?:.*?\'(_*?-*?.*?)\'/',$response, $matches);

Then I removed the word "challenge :" and the quotations using str_replace.